# Manage parameter into a function

Tags: javascript, html, perl

I am working now on a drag & drop system of elements + management of areas to display  according to available area, all that in a modal during an onclick event.
When I drag & drop the element "Image" in one of the 3 big areas just below, I offer the possibility to the user of upload images thanks to the button " Import an image ", and if this user already had upload images previously, he can find a list of all the images by clicking on "Choose since the library ".

The problem is that by imagining that the user already had upload an image before, and that he wishes to add the image in the area, the link must be inserted into the input generated in the area in question.

I do not manage to display the url of the image in the  of the area

It's on the choosePicture() function that I have to manage his entrance parameter target.

Some images of the result which I would like to have :

Here, it's when I drag & drop the "Image" button in an area 
[image]

Here, it's when I click on "Choose since the library" : 
[image]

Here, after having clicked on the "Choose" button, the link appears in the  area.
[image]

Perl code :

```
sub listPictures
{
    my $self = shift;

    my $query = $self->query;

    my $session = $self->param('session');
    my $profile = $session->param('profile');

    if(checkUserId($profile->{'uid'}) ne 'SUCCESS')
    {
        return $self->redirect('?rm=login');
    }

    my $User = User->newFromId($profile->{'uid'});
    if($User eq 'NOT_FOUND')
    {
        return $self->redirect('?rm=login');
    }

    my $tableContent = '';
    my $pictures = $User->listPictures();

    if(ref($pictures) eq 'STRING')
    {
        return '<p>Your library is empty</p>';
    }
    $log->info($pictures);
    foreach my $picture (@$pictures)
    {
        $tableContent .= '<tr><td><label>'.$picture->{'name'}.'</label></td>';
        $tableContent .= '<td><button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn choiceBtn" name="'.$picture->{'url'}.'"  onclick=\'insertPicture("'.$picture->{'url'}.'")\'>Choisir</button>';
        $tableContent .= '<button class="btn" onclick="window.open("'.$picture->{'url'}.'", "_blank", "scrollbars=yes,status=yes")">Voir</button></td></tr>';
    }

    return $tableContent;
}
```

`link to check my code` [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQBdaQ)